# Mapping top level items and embedded arrays with RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

Given the following JSON structure:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "anno": "blah",
    "domini": null,
    "locations": [
      {
        "data": {
          "lat": null,
          "lon": null
         },
         "data": {
           "lat": null,
           "lon": null
         }
       }
     ]
  }
}
```

How do I set up RestKit mappings for this scenario? I though I had it, but I'm unable to map the top-level foo items anno, and domini. I can successfully map locations on its own, but not in coordination with foo.

I've done this successfully in the past, but something is escaping me now.

**Foo.h**

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *anno;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *domini;
@end
```

**Location.h**

```
@interface LocationData : NSObject
@property NSString *lat;
@property NSString *lon;
@end
```

**Controller.m**

```
RKObjectMapping *fooMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Foo class]];
[fooMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"anno", @"domini"]];

RKObjectMapping *locationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Location class]];
[locationMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"lat",@"lon"]];

[fooMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"location" toKeyPath:@"location" withMapping: locationMapping]];

RKResponseDescriptor *fooReponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:dataMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"foo" keyPath:@"foo" statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

RKResponseDescriptor *locationResponseDescriptor =
        [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:locationdMapping
                                                     method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                pathPattern:nil
                                                    keyPath:@"foo.location"
                                                statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
```

I think that's all of the important stuff. Hopefully in my zeal to pare down how much text I was posting I didn't leave anything important out.

**EDIT** 2015-03-29

```
- (void)loadChildren {

NSDictionary *queryParams = @{@"sort" : @"new"};

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:redditPath
                                       parameters:queryParams
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                              _children = mappingResult.array;
                                              [self.tableView reloadData];
                                          }
                                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@"You mean YOU'RE the lunatic who's responsible for almost destroying my ship? : %@", error);
                                          }];
}
```

redditpath is set earlier using...

```
redditPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/r/%@/new.json", subRedditToLoad];
```

Where subRedditToLoad is, in this case, **aww**.

Comment: Show your code and model. What does the trace log tell you?

Comment: The key path for locations is wrong. What GET are you calling (what path)?

Comment: _The key path for locations is wrong._ I suspected as much. I'm not sure what you're asking in re: the GET?

Comment: You're using an object manager to make the request? Show that code.

Answer (score 0):

In your XCDataModel Take an Entity with named Foo.
Set Property of anno and vomini.

Also Create another Entity **Location**.
Set a property named **data** with type Transformable.

Add Relationship at Foo for Location entity put it many relationship.

Call mapping for Foo Like:

```
[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"foo" toKeyPath:@"Foo" withMapping:[Location objectMappingForLocation:Enum]]];
```